# Python project relative modules import

Tags: python, import, module

I am sure the question might seem pretty stupid, but searching around didn't yield me much result, so a redirection towards a response would be quite welcome.

So, I have a Python project with nested modules:

```
src
 |-package_1
  |-__init__.py
  |-module_1_1
  |-module_1_2
 |-package_2
  |-__init__.py
  |module_2_1
  |module_2_2
 |-main_module
 |-__init__.py
```

From the `main_module` I import the contents of `package_2` and from modules inside `package_2` I import contents of `package_1` modules with the similar statements:

(`main_module`)

```
from package_2.module_2_1 import foo
```

(`module_2_1`)

```
from package_1.module_1_1 import bar
```

It all works well as a long as I run

```
Python main_module
```

but as soon as I try to run, for instance to use a function of the `module_2_1` on it's own

```
Python module_2_1,
```

if fails with a message that it could not resolve the following import:

```
from package_1.module_1_1 import bar
```

From my understanding, Python is not aware of where it should go look for package_1, because it is not aware of where the project root is.

As a remedy, I am currently pre-pending the following line to all the inner modules to properly resolve the import:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    os.chdir("..")
```

But it just don't feel right.

What would be the correct way of solving this problem?

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` s?

Comment: why do you need to run your program from `module_2_1`, is `main_module` your package's entry point?

Comment: Yes, __init__.py are inside all the packages and the src. Good point, but I checked it.

Comment: Sorry I don't know the technical solution - I've never run into so complicated python project before. But I'm wondering if the directory structure is good. In my opinion, the whole meaning of divide up package1 and package 2 is because they are _independent_. If one should import another, then package1 should be embedded in package 2.

Comment: Package 1 defines core functions for the 8-9 other packages in the group. Think of it as a config/common tools folder. Common enough to be shared throughout the project, yet not general enough to be installed as an independent module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke it properly in the first place. Change to `src/` and run:

```
python -m package_2.module_2_1
```

Comment: However, if I fire a Python shell in the `src/` directory and then import, everything seems to work just fine

Comment: That would be because I got the package name wrong.

Comment: However, is the re a way for executing the file from the directory within `package1/` and not from `src/`? For instance by manipulating the `__init__.py` or the `__package__` attribute within individual modules?

Comment: Certainly nothing sane.